# Wordpress Post # of #

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm looking for an easy way to assign a post number to each post in wordpress and display it out of the total number of posts. A little info:

1. There will be about 100 "posts", each on its own page
2. I want users to click through each post, so start at post 1 and click "next post" to get to post 2
3. I want it to say post 4/100 at the top for each post
4. I want the URL to have the post name in it

I was going to use WP-PageNavi and set each page to display 1 post, however I need the url to show /post-name/ and not /page/2/

I know I can count total number of posts pretty easily, any idea how I can assign a number to each post without having to do it manually? I'd like to sort by date added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what I wanted:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/375293?replies=5

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking at the problem from the wrong angle. A post url contains post-name, so you need to change your previous/next nav links to go to the previous/next post rather than the previous/next index page.

Comment: Yes, sorry I didnt make that clear. Each post you can have a prev/next link. So I want to have those links but also indicate its incremental position within all posts.